# Error 401 when trying to deploy app from Google App Engine Launcher

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, http-status-code-401

I am having some issues with launching my first app from **Google App Engine Launcher**. I have already signed up for an account at the App Engine site. After I click on the deploy button, I get the deploy application to Google **popup** where I enter in the info I gave at sign up. I then get this error:

```
Starting update of app: isabelleengineapp, version: 1
12:49 PM Getting current resource limits.
Password for swissian@gmail.com: Use an application-specific password instead of your regular account password.
See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?answer=185833
However, now the recommended way to log in is using OAuth2. See
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#oauth
2013-01-29 12:49:22,607 ERROR appcfg.py:2203 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. Aborting. 
Error 401: --- begin server output ---
Must authenticate first.
--- end server output ---
2013-01-29 12:49:22 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Now, I think that this may because I have 2 step verification set up for my **Google** account but I have no idea what to do other than trying using an *application* specific password when getting the deploying popup, but that did not work. Any ideas?!

Comment: I just had to do this myself. There's a link in the error message. You have to follow it: http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833 Then generate the one-time password on the following page. That password will be what you have to put in for the password to update AppEngine.

Answer (score 3):

You can try passing the `--oauth2` option to `appcfg.py`.

This is an alternative way of authenticating that avoids having to deal with passwords.

More details here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Password-less_login_with_OAuth2